# PHP: The best way to check if 3 variables are identical?

Tags: php, variables, syntax

Forgive me if this is a common thing but I'm not sure how I should go about it.

I would like to see if three variables are identical to each other

I thought i could do this:

```
<?php
 if ($one == $two == $three) {
  echo "they all match.";
 } else {
  echo "one of these variables do not match."; 
 }
?>
```

But i guess that's not possible.

Is there a syntax for this? or do I have to check them individually/with && or || ?

I'm aware that checking them separately would give more accuracy (and is probably better practice) but for this particular situation it doesn't matter which one doesn't match.

Comment: Comes up commonly in interview questions : How to tell if a triangle is equilateral

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use:

```
if ( $one === $two && $two === $three )
    echo "they all match."
else
    echo "one of these variables do not match.";
```

- #1 == #2 (no type coercion)
- #2 == #3 (no type coercion)
- ∴ #1 == #2 == #3

Comment: Thank you for the explanation at the bottom of your answer, I got it when you said it and had an 'Ah-ha!' moment, but you illustrated it wonderfully which will make it easier to remember. Thank you. (Also, fastest answer. Gratz. =) )

Answer (score 7):

Here's an alternative solution that might be helpful. It will be particularly useful if your variables are already in an array.

```
$a = array($one, $two, $three);

if(count(array_unique($a)) == 1){
  // all match
}
else {
  // some items do not match
}
```

Comment: Ooh, "array unique"? awesome. Thanks for that, it'll come in handy later on in my script =)

Answer (score 4):

You have you use `&&`. Fortunately, by the transitive property of `==`, you only have to check two out of three `:)`.

```
if ($one == $two && $two == $three) {
    echo "they all match.";
} else {
    echo "one of these variables do not match."; 
}
```

Want a "do what I mean" language? Use Python.

```
>>> a = 'foo'
>>> b = 'foo'
>>> c = 'foo'
>>> a == b == c
True
```

Comment: hahaha, that last snippet looks fun. I'm going to learn python one of these days, just don't know when.. I've heard many good things about it ^__^ thanks for your quick response =)

Comment: Much `<3` for Python. Of course you can also do stuff like `x < y <= z` instead of `x < y and y <= z` as well.

Answer (score 3):

Dont think you can do it simpler then:

```
if ($one == $two && $two == $three)
```

Comment: Seems this is a common thing after all. haha. Thank you for your quick response =)