# Test if two variables equal one variable in PHP if statement

Tags: php

**Instead of writing out**

```
if ($var1 = $something && $var2 == $something)
    echo 'this';
```

**is it possible to write something similar to this instead**

```
if ($var1 && $var2 == $something)
    echo 'this';
```

Comment: no. why would you want to? if typing the extra few characters is a problem write a class or function. in my opinion that would just make your code harder to read though. also you need to use the double == not the singel. = is an assignment operator for assigning variables and == is for comparing values.

Comment: Why do you want to write this expression in another way?

Comment: no, it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

no, not really. There is no shortcutting operator in PHP that does what you describe, though you could write a function in PHP that saves on typing if you're doing this comparison regularly.

```
 function allEqual($value1, $value2, $value3) {
     return $value1 == $value2 && $value2 == $value3;
 }

 // Usage:
 if( allEqual( $var1, $something, $var2 ) ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array($var1, $var2, $something);

if(count(array_unique($a)) == 1){
  // all match
}
else {
  // some items do not match
}
```

Ref: [PHP: The best way to check if 3 variables are identical?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920511/php-the-best-way-to-check-if-3-variables-are-identical)